# Open the activity when device was locked

Tags: android, android-activity, locking

i'm running an API in service class. When i get the particular response from that api i'm opening the AutoPlay activity. For calling the activity i wrote

```
Intent intent = new Intent(BackgroundService.this, AutoPlay.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

and inside of onCreate in the AutoPlay activity i wrote the fallowing code to open the activity when device was locked

```
Window window = getWindow();
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
```

or

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON|
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

but above code was not opening the activity when device was locked. So, please any one help me to achive this

Comment: you can't do that. all you can do is keep one activity (if possible) and take FrameLayout instead. make it visible and invisible as you need.

Comment: ok i'll try that. Thank you for your valiable comment...